# possible to get POSTed parameters and RESPONSE content in Opera Dragonfly?

Tags: post, opera, opera-dragonfly

When I look at the Network tab in Opera Dragonfly, I'm not seeing POSTEd parameters or the RESPONSE content. Here's what I see:

```
 Raw Response
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.1
 Date: Thu, 15 Jul 2010 12:43:19 GMT
 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Pragma: no-cache
 Expires: -1
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: 22320
```

In Dragonfly, is there a way to examine the parameters posted to the server and the actual response from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet. Microsoft Fiddler HTTP debugger is a good replacement if you have an OS to run it on.

Answer (score 7):

The ability for Opera Dragonfly to get this information from the Opera rendering engine (Presto) should be included in Opera 11. We are currently working on implementing the client side code in Opera Dragonfly to support this and other Network Inspector features, such as editing headers and replaying requests.

*EDIT:*

**As of July 2011 (Opera Dragonfly 1.1) it is possible.**

To see POST parameters in Opera Dragonfly click on `Network` tab followed by `Network log` subtab. **NOTE:** It requires reloading the page, if the page was already loaded while opening Opera Dragonfly.

Comment: Its possible now. http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/the-feature-you-ve-all-been-waiting-for-and-more